# Android Dynamic Image Gallery

Tags: android, html, dynamic, gallery

Is it possible to build a dynamic image gallery for Android. I have a bunch of pages that describe beaches and it have a bunch of images particular to each beach?

If this is possible would I be able to give the user the option to download then images after they have downloaded the application?

Another option is, I have an HTML5 gallery that works in a web view, is there a way to embed that in my app?

Comment: So you want to load the images in a gallery in the app
?

Comment: Yes, but not via the net at run time. I want the whole app to work offline while the user is away from home.

Comment: Well all you need to do is download the images to cache when the user is home.

Comment: so u can think of packaging ur images in the drawable folder, dats d only way 2 make it offline

Comment: Does anyone know of a place I can find code with best practices in this regard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android images in /assets or res/raw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423460/android-images-in-assets-or-res-raw)