# Loading a file from res folder in android test project

Tags: android, android-testing

In a testcase I need to load a picture which is available in my testproject in the folder

```
/myproject/res/drawable-hdpi/attachment.png
```

I tried it already by using the InstrumentationTestCase and storing the file in the /res/raw folder and loading it with this, but the R file does not contain my attachment.png

```
Context testContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
InputStream input = testContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.?????????)
```

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use raw to save images, used drawable o asset ;)

[Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)

[Android images in /assets or res/raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423460/android-images-in-assets-or-res-raw)

Comment: With using the assets folder instead, I could load it this way           Context testContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
  InputStream input = testContext.getAssets().open("attachment.png");